# Show a dialog when user clicks the spinner

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I am making an application in which i have many spinner. My minimum API is 15. What i want is that when user clicks on the spinner and a dialog should popup instead of dropdown. I tried finding it on google but no success for me. I also read somewhere that instead of spinner I can use a TextView or a button to show a dialog.

If the user select a particular value, how can I get what the user selected?

I want to show my spinner like this:
[image]

My spinner code:

```
professionArray = getResources ().getStringArray (R.array.Profession);
    Arrays.sort (professionArray, 1, professionArray.length);
    profession = new ArrayAdapter<String> (c, R.layout.spinner_textview, professionArray);
    profession.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
    spCategory.setAdapter (profession);
```

Comment: setDropDownViewResource is for dropdown menu... try something else there

Answer (score 1):

You can change spinnerMode like this:

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

or follow this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: i did that but then to is displaying like a dropdown not dialog

Comment: So,you must create a custom dialog and listen the spinner OnTouch event.

Comment: thats what but i dnt know abt it?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link..

[Spinner Basics - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Spinner_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=82&aaid=105)

And Read This for Basic

[Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

This may help you..

Comment: show me your code when you call your spinner adapter

Answer (score 0):

@Anuj, hope this helps.

Spinner declaration in layout

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" 
    android:prompt="@string/your_gender"/>
```

Code in the activity itself

```
spCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);     
    String[] professionArray = getResources().getStringArray (R.array.Profession);
    Arrays.sort (professionArray, 1, professionArray.length);
    ArrayAdapter<String> profession = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, professionArray);
    profession.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    spCategory.setAdapter(profession);
```

About checking which item is selected, it depends on what you want to do: 
If you want to perform an action anytime a new item is  selected, you have to set an OnItemSelectedListener. That can be done this way:

```
spCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("item selected id = " + arg2 + professionArray[arg2]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Also if you want to check the selected item when maybe a button on the screen is selected. You can do so by calling the spinner's getSelectedItemPosition method to get the selected item's position in your array. e.g.:

```
int i = spCategory.getSelectedItemPosition();
System.out.println("item id = " + i + professionArray[i]);
```